# Object speed is changing randomly in SFML C++

Tags: c++, game-physics, sfml, game-development

I have a created a little program in SFML C++ where I want an object to move. But my problem is the movement speed is not constant, sometime speed is dropping randomly and the movement is not smooth at all.
[Video Link](https://vimeo.com/813323332)
If you take a closer look the speed is not constant
My Source code

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
// 10^6
int main()
{

    float dx = 0.000001;
    float dy = 0.03;
    int w = 720;
    int h = 480;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(w, h), "Sf Test");
    sf::CircleShape r1(20);
    r1.setFillColor(sf::Color(250, 0, 0));
    sf::Vector2f objPos(0.0, 0.0);
    r1.setOrigin(objPos);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        if (r1.getPosition().y > h || r1.getPosition().y < 0)
        {
            dy *= -1;
        }

        objPos.y += dy;
        r1.setPosition(objPos);
        // std::cout << r1.getPosition().y << std::endl;

        window.clear();
        window.draw(r1);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to stop this behavior also how to make the movement speed smooth.

Comment: I don't see a time period. Speed is change in distance over time. I see nothing that controls how frequently `dy` is applied to the objects position. What I do see is an event loop that will capture 0 to (?) events and discard them until the queue is empty or a close event is read.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot control when the system is going to schedule/unschedule your code for execution, you're going to want to put a time element in your delta calculation.
So,

```
objPos.y += ( speedY * deltaTime );
```

You will need to calculate the 'deltaTime' from loop-to-loop.  'deltaTime' will be the time since the last loop happened.  You can use the sf::Clock class and work off of 'getElapsedTime()'.

Comment: Can you share a source from where I can learn more

Comment: Here is a link to a discussion: https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=7068.0 . Here is a link to a video: https://youtu.be/qplKFkcpBMw